# React native Android VerticalDownSwipeJump bug

Tags: android, react-native

I use the VerticalDownSwipeJump when rendering a new scene in my React Native project. New scenes are supposed to come into view from above, pushing the current scene out of view.
On iOS this works as expected, on Android however the new scene being rendered comes into view from the above AND the right side as well.

Not sure why this is the case on android and not on iOS... 
I haven't found any reports of this issue on SO or the React Native Github.

Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old question, but maybe somebody will have the same problem. First of all, You can customize this view. The animations are defined here:

> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfig.js

Below steps which I have made:

1.
I've created my own object:

```
var FromTheRightCustom = {
  opacity: {
    value: 1.0,
    type: 'constant',
  },
  scaleX: {
    value: 1,
    type: 'constant',
  },
  scaleY: {
    value: 1,
    type: 'constant',
  },
};
```

2. I've replaced FromTheRight to FromTheRightCustom in two places:

i)

```
var FromTheDown = {
  ...FromTheRightCustom,
```

ii)

```
var FromTheTop = {
  ...FromTheRightCustom,
```

The only difference, that in Android you will have empty space made by StatusBar. This can be fix e.g. by backgroundColor of navigator (sceneStyle).

Comment: To clearyfiy, empty space in my project was caused by background dimensions. I have deifined it as height: window.height, width: window.width